# Inserting random data from a table into existing rows in another

Tags: python, mysql

I'm creating dumb dataset. I have 2 tables. First table is `SENSOR` while the other is `AREA`. The `SENSOR` table has 1 column called **sensorID** already filled with 100 unique rows while the `AREA` table has 1 column called **area** that has 32 unique rows. I want to create a column called **AREA** in the `SENSOR` table and fill it with random values from `AREA` table.

I tried to do it with this code but it just add the values to new rows with NULL values in the sensorID column:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM area")

results = mycursor.fetchall()

col = "INSERT INTO sensor(area) VALUES(%s)"
val = []

for _ in results:
    val.append(random.choice(results))

mycursor.executemany(col,val)
raindb.commit()
```

Comment: Insert inserts new values, generating new rows. Update can change the values of the existing rows

Comment: Is there a column `area` in `sensor`?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Thanks. I get the idea. I created ```area``` column in ```sensor``` but I have to specify which row to update. (UPDATE sensor SET area = '%s" where sensorID = ...). Is there a way to update all rows in column area with random data from ```area``` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` that sets the `area` with a subquery that gets areas in random order and only takes the top one.

```
UPDATE sensor
       SET area = (SELECT area
                          FROM area
                          ORDER BY rand()
                          LIMIT 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=e821edfabddd22741b770d762a53dd20)